# Allow the user to change the colors of my app

Tags: java, android

Hey guys I want to know how to allow the user to change my app's theme,for example my app colors is red and black,I want the user to be able to change it to colors that I choose before,such as red and blue or blue and red,in other words i want to allow the user to change the color and to change tbe general color and the accent color,just as this in the pic:

[image]

Comment: did you try something

Comment: Thanks found the answer

Answer (score 2):

Found it guys thanks for helping wish I helped u too

http://mobile.developer.com/ws/android/changing-your-android-apps-theme-dynamically.html